# Safe way to move Pagefile.sys SBS 2008

Tags: windows-sbs-2008, pagefile, migration

I would like to move my pagefile.sys from my c: to my d: on SBS 2008 what is the best way for me to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the standard System Properties > Performance Options to move the Pagefile, but make sure that SYSTEM has full control on D:.

EDIT

More detailed instructions:

Right-click Computer > Advanced system settings > Advanced tab > click Settings... under Performance > Advanced tab then Change button.

Comment: i cannot see that option in sbs 2008 to move the pagesys

Comment: It is there - run SystemPropertiesAdvanced.exe, click on the "Options" button in the "Performance" section of the shown tab, navigate to the "Advanced" tab of the newly-shown performance options dialog and click on the change button of the "Virtual memory" section.

Comment: OK i am there but how do i migrate it from my c to the d:. do i click c:/ no page file then on d: change to system manaaged size?

Comment: @ben950: Correct. You'll need to reboot to make the changes.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a new page file on your D: volume and removing the pagefile from C: should be safe. The limitation of older Windows versions where no kernel or complete memory dumps could be created whenever there was no sufficiently sized page file on the boot volume has been removed with Windows Server 2008 - you can use the [DedicatedDumpFile option](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/969028/en-us) to configure a dump file location on any of your volumes.